# read hardcoded maze into a multi dimensional array

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner, filereader

i tried to ask earlier but i think i asked in the wrong way.

i need to read a txt file into a 2D array.

my txt file is a block of characters that will represent walls, paths and outside.

its a hard coded maze so the characters have to read into the array in the same configuration as in the file.

ive tried multiple approaches but i can't wrap my head around it
heres the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("//Mac//Users//Tucker//SPSU//Programming 2//mazehardcode");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    String mazeCode = fileScanner.nextLine();
    char buffer [][]= new char[80][80];
    new Thread(new Monitor()).start();
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
    for(int i = 0;i<buffer.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<buffer[i].length;j++){

        }
    }
    }
```

thats as far as i can get without error so i need help
the errors i get have to do with converting string to char, or char to char[][] or anything along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

If your tilemap looks in the file like this:

```
11111
10001
11101
10001
11111
```

You can read in every line and loop through every character and assign it to the `char buffer[][]`.

```
int currentLine = 0;
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()){

    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0;i<line.length();i++){
        buffer[currentLine][i] = line.charAt(i);
    }
    currentLine++;
}
```

If you store it only in one line like this:

```
1111110001111011000111111
```

You can do some modulo and division.
**Edit:** works only if the width  of the tilemap is the same as the length of the buffer

```
if(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0;i<line.length();i++){
        buffer[i/buffer.length][i%buffer.length] = line.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

But be aware of the actual size of the level so maybe you will have in the first line the size of it, if the size will vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the block of characters from file like example mention below.

```
#########
#0000111#
#########
```

You can use System.Arraycopy to copy whole line into the buffer after converting the String to Char Array.

```
int lineCount=0;
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
  String line = fileScanner.nextLine();                                           
  System.arraycopy(line.toCharArray(),0,buffer[lineCount++],0,line.length());  
}
```